# .NET Method Not Found Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, assemblies, methodnotfound

When I start my application I get the following error:

```
method not found microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult
```

Does anyone know what causes this? I have tried repairing my .NET installation.

Note: This error only occurs on one machine.  On every other machine it works fine which makes me think something with the .NET assemblies was corrupted.  It was working fine on the broken machine a few days ago.

Proof of Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What versions of the framework and Visual Studio are you using and do you have the VS11 beta installed by any chance?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2005 and .NET 2.0.

Comment: Well, you need to show us your code, but I have the feeling that the code must do something very strange, because [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.msgboxresult.aspx) indeed isn't a method but an enumeration

Comment: Can you ensure that all SPs are applied and are the same on the working vs. non-working machine?

Comment: I've gotten mysterious "method not found" errors before and it turned out to be corrupt native images.  NGEN puts them in the GAC.  So if you go to the GAC, and find the native image for the assembly that has the missing method (Microsot.VisualBasic.dll?), delete it, and see if that helps.  When I had this problem there was a chain of errors, so I deleted all native images related to SQL Server.  This might not be your issue, but it's easy to test.

Comment: Clearly you typed in the error message by hand instead of copy/pasting it.  Bad idea, what you typed doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz - I think Hans was (sort of) trying to point out that you can hit Ctrl+C on any windows message box, and it will copy the text (and title and buttons), and you could have posted that instead of typing it yourself.  But it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somewhat likely there are corrupt assemblies in your .NET installation.  I have fixed similar problems like this before, and I hope I can share some insights to help you solve this relatively quickly, as it is extremely annoying.

1. Use [this tool here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) to verify your installation of .NET 2.0.  As a note, this can be used to verify *any* version of the .NET Framework.
2. Regardless if errors are found, I would try repairing .NET 2.0.  If your problem goes away, great.  However, if that doesn't work, I would try uninstalling it and then re-installing it.

   - Now, if you're on Vista or Later, you might not actually be able to remove it via Control Panel -> Programs and Settings.  If this is the case, the following steps probably won't work either.  You *might* have to repair your OS installation.
3. If you've done the above steps and you *still* can't get it to work, or step 2 fails (which can happen on corrupt installations), then you'll want to try using the [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

   - **Read the blog carefully and make sure you understand the risks/caveats related to this tool**
   - You will likely have to re-install other version of the .NET framework if you remove .NET 2.0.  That is why I listed this step last.

The last time I dealt with this kind of problem, the only thing that worked for me was step 3.  Hopefully you have better luck than I did.

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely helpful.  I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like .NET installation is corrupted. Try to reinstall .NET Framework.
Use .NET from Microsoft's website. It is known that some versions of AutoCAD have been shipped with modified version of .NET.